# extracting data using bs4 from columns with same td class name

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape a table from this URl https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL.
this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as  np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
url=('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL')
r=requests.get(url)
r
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
date=[]
t=soup.find_all(class_="W(100%) M(0)") 
for i in t:
you=i.find_all('td',class_='Py(10px) Ta(start) Pend(10px)')
```

I have no problem getting the date column.
when I ran the below code for the 2nd column, it returns all the
data for the remaining 6 columns

```
for i in t:
u=i.find_all(class_='Py(10px) Pstart(10px)')
for k in u:
  print(k.text)
```

I want to get all of each individual columns one at a  time, that is for open, high, low, close etc. how can I accomplish this using bs4?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop by `select_one('td:nth-of-type(1)')`

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as  np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from random import randint
url=('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL')
r=requests.get(url)
r
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
date=[]
t=soup.find_all(class_="BdT Bdc($seperatorColor) Ta(end) Fz(s) Whs(nw)") 
for i in t:
    if i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)'):
        date = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(1)').text
        start = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').text
        high = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)').text
        low = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text
        close = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(5)').text
        adjClose = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(6)').text 
        volume = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(7)').text 
        print(date, start, high, low, close, adjClose, volume)
```

**Output**

```
Dec 31, 2020 134.08 134.74 131.72 132.69 132.69 98,990,400
Dec 30, 2020 135.58 135.99 133.40 133.72 133.72 96,452,100
Dec 29, 2020 138.05 138.79 134.34 134.87 134.87 121,047,300
Dec 28, 2020 133.99 137.34 133.51 136.69 136.69 124,486,200
Dec 24, 2020 131.32 133.46 131.10 131.97 131.97 54,930,100
Dec 23, 2020 132.16 132.43 130.78 130.96 130.96 88,223,700
Dec 22, 2020 131.61 134.41 129.65 131.88 131.88 168,904,800
Dec 21, 2020 125.02 128.31 123.45 128.23 128.23 121,251,600
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. had a  hard time tryna figure out  how to go about it

Comment: though when I tried for other columns, it returns a ' NoneType' object has no attribute text'  AttributeError

Comment: Could you provide the changes you have made to reproduce, please.

Comment: for i in t:
    date = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(1)').text
    start = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(2)').text
    high = i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)').text
    print(date, start, high)

Comment: Saw the issue, there is an additional line in data, that just print out the *dividende*, so you have to check for a the column like that `if i.select_one('td:nth-of-type(3)'):` at the beginning - take a look at my edit 2 days ago, that fixed that point.

Comment: but i've solved it using
high= i.select('#Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable-Proxy > section > div.Pb\(10px\).Ovx\(a\).W\(100\%\) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(n+1) > td:nth-child(7) > span') and  created a new loop to convert to text. it worked and didn't return any error